# Is it possible to add webhooks to a gist?

Tags: github, webhooks, gist

Basically, the same way as I can set up a push webhook for a Github repo, can I set it up for a Github gist? I looked around, and I suspect not since there's no documentation for it.

If it is impossible, is there anyway to get notifications whenever a gist is updated? If not, I'm ready to implement a solution that polls every few minutes, but I prefer the notification based solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I confirmed it for myself. Github doesn't allow any kind of code to be run on its server's during/before/after a push, so it has webhooks for developers to take advantage of that. Gist does not support either actual Git hooks or Github webhooks.

Comment: Doubly confirmed; found this in their documentation, explicitly stating that "this event is no longer created". - https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#gistevent

Answer (score 3):

> is there anyway to get notifications whenever a gist is updated?

Since May 8th, 2019, it is possible.

See "[Gist notifications](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-05-08-gist-notifications/) "

> You can now receive notifications for new conversations occurring on gists. Similar to issues and pull requests, you can opt out of these notifications at any time.

[The documentation](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-gists#receiving-notifications-for-gist-activity) now includes:

> ### Receiving notifications for gist activity
>
> You'll receive a notification when:
>
> - You are the author of the gist.
> - Someone mentions you in a gist.
> - You comment in another persons's gist.
> - You subscribe to a gist, by clicking Subscribe at the top any gist.

In your case, maybe you can combine that with [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions), which does allow some code execution on the server side, including some [involving notification](https://github.com/sdras/awesome-actions#notifications-and-messages).